# nRF24LO1 not receiving ack package

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I am attempting to make a two way transmitter with two nRF24L01 modules and two Arduino Unos. I have the transmitter working just fine but I am attempting to send data back with an Ack package but the transmitter is seemingly not receiving anything in the ack package. Here is my TX code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN

const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.setAutoAck(0, true);
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.stopListening();
}

void loop() {
    const char text[] = "Hi";
    const char data[] = "";
    radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
    delay(100);
    if (radio.isAckPayloadAvailable() == true) {
      radio.read(&data, sizeof(data));
      Serial.print(data);
    }
    else {
      Serial.print("Not recieved");
      
    }
}
```

and RX

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>


RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN


const byte address[6] = "00001";



void setup() {
  radio.setAutoAck(0, true);
  radio.enableAckPayload();
  radio.enableDynamicPayloads();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.startListening();

}

void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    char text[32] = "";
    radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
    Serial.println(text);
    const char data[] = "got";
    radio.writeAckPayload(3, &data, sizeof(data));
  }
}
```

I have looked online and none of the things I have found have helped. Enabling Ack packages on the TX side makes it so the transmission doesn't work, and I've tried adjusting the pipe the package is being send through but nothing has worked.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it's a problem with a power adapter yl-105 nrf24l01.

After disconnecting from the adapter and connecting it to the Arduino (3.3v I get from Bread Board Test adapter [aliexpress.com](https://vi.aliexpress.com/item/1005003672900139.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.174.1cc51802WDY9B7&gatewayAdapt=glo2vnm))

And now it works well